# Merge candidates: [automated-tests] and [automated-testing]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I think [automated-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automated-testing) should be merged into [automated-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automated-tests) and a synonym should be set up in the same direction.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tags have been merged or merginated (if that's a word).

[automated-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automated-tests) will be the primary tag now as it already had more posts tagged with it.